# better search feature in pdf

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, evince, pdfgrep

I want to search a word like **fooonetwo** in one pdf. So the point is I do not know the real ward is **foo_one_two** or **foo.one.two** or **foo-one-two** or **foo-one_two!** or ... .

Or better to say I want to search for words which at the same time include **foo** and **one** and **two**. So I remember in the database we have kind of this feature : For example a query for looking for  words which start by **foo** and also include **one** and **two**. So is there any PDF viewer to do that? What PDF viewer and how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pdfgrep` to search inside `.pdf` files using patterns. First you have to install `pdfgrep` package,

```
 sudo apt-get install pdfgrep
```

And your command should be,

```
pdfgrep -in 'foo.one.two' file.pdf
```

Dot inside the above pattern will match any character(It doesn't represent a literal dot). So it will find `foo.one.two`,`foo-one-two`,`foo_one_two`.

Syntax:

```
pdfgrep -in pattern file.pdf
```